# Refining my overlay's behaviour

Tags: html, css, overlay, responsive

coding rookie here. I have some overlays that displays some text upon hovering  over an image. There are two things I'd like to change about their behaviour that I'm not clever enough to work out.

You can see them in action here

http://www.brightonyouthcentre.org.uk/skatepark

Firstly, at the moment the blue overlay's height is 20% of the image's height. If possible I'd like to make it so the height is relative to the amount of text there is, instead of a static size. No idea where to start with this bit.

Secondly, I don't want this behaviour on mobile, so I want to shift the overlay below the image and have it appear by default. At the moment it does this but doesn't seem to sit in the right place, and the method I've used causes some issues with the spacing between each image. Also I'm guessing if I fix issue 1, then my current attempt will go out the window. Any help with either of these would be appreciated!

CSS

```
.home-grid-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.home-grid-header {
    background-color:#e4a628;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding:10px;
    color:white;
    }

.home-grid-image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.home-grid-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;

}

.home-grid-block:hover .home-grid-overlay {
  height: 20%;
  padding-top:5px;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .home-grid-overlay {
  height: 20%;
  margin-bottom:-20%;
  padding-top:5px;
}
}

.home-grid-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="http://www.brightonyouthcentre.org.uk/skatepark/skateboard-tuition/">
<div class="home-grid-block">
 <div class="home-grid-header">Header above image</div>
  <img class="home-grid-image" src="http://www.brightonyouthcentre.org.uk/skatepark/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2018/07/summer-tuition-sq.jpg">
  <div class="home-grid-overlay">
    <div class="home-grid-text">This text will vary in length every time. </div>
  </div>
</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**For auto height.**

.home-grid-block:hover .home-grid-overlay {
  height: auto;
  padding:25px;
}


**Mobile Fix New code**

    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {


        .home-grid-overlay {
          height: auto;
          position: relative;
          padding:25px;
        }
        }
```

Comment: Beautiful, these both work great thank you. Just had to add/remove a couple of things and it's working good. It's fixed the spacing issue between each item as well. Thanks!